# Condensed IF function - EXCEL

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

How would I condense this function?

```
=SUM(IF(B2="Cash",D2,0)+IF(B3="Cash",D3,0)+IF(B4="Cash",D4,0)+IF(B5="Cash",D5,0)+IF(B6="Cash",D6,0)+IF(B7="Cash",D7,0)+IF(B8="Cash",D8,0)+IF(B9="Cash",D9,0))
```

It asks if `B2` has the value `Cash` then get the value of `D2`, else it has a value of `0`.

I want it to do this for *every* cell in the columns `B` and `D` so that I can add them all up? How would I do this?

Comment: Jonathan, which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: why not use sumif function?  ( you can say sum this range's values if a condition is true.

Comment: @pnuts : that's not my question, it's Jonathan's one
But the answers seem to good ones

Comment: yes, in order to help and provide a compatible answer, because some functions are not available in 2003 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,"Cash",D:D)
```

Comment: This worked beautifully with not much code needed at all, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `=sumif()` or do you need to know the individual cells values for some reason?

[image]

Comment: I'll take the high ground and let the OP author decide.

Comment: Thank you for showing exactly what it does. Both of you helped me, thank you.